# Python Mediapipe replace pose landmark line drawings with custom image drawings

Tags: python, graphics, drawing, mediapipe

I'm using a webcam to stream a video and would like to use mediapipe to estimate and replace/blur a user's face with a custom yellow image and the user's eyes with a heart (❤) emoji and the user's lips with a smile drawing.

The code I currently have below is only drawing landmark lines.

Could someone please help me alter the code below to achieve the result as described?

Thanks in advance!

Current image result:

[image: Current result]

Desired Image result:

[image: Desired Result]

The current code:

```py
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

## initialize pose estimator
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    # read frame
    _, frame = cap.read()
    try:
         # resize the frame for portrait video
         # frame = cv2.resize(frame, (350, 600))
         # convert to RGB
         frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
         
         # process the frame for pose detection
         pose_results = pose.process(frame_rgb)
         # print(pose_results.pose_landmarks)
         
         # draw skeleton on the frame
         mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, pose_results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
         # display the frame
         cv2.imshow('Output', frame)
    except:
         break
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
         break
          
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Mediapipe replace chest pose landmark line drawings with custom image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78209901/python-mediapipe-replace-chest-pose-landmark-line-drawings-with-custom-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heart can be drawn using equation found here:
https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-draw-a-heart-using-Python

```
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp
import numpy as np

def draw_heart(image, center, size, color):
    t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 0.1)
    x = size * (16*np.sin(t)**3)
    y = size * (13*np.cos(t) - 5*np.cos(2*t) - 2*np.cos(3*t) - np.cos(4*t))
    x = x + center[0]
    y = center[1] - y
    x = x.astype(int)
    y = y.astype(int)
    for i in range(len(x) - 1):
        cv2.line(image, (x[i], y[i]), (x[i+1], y[i+1]), color, 2)

def landmark_to_image_coords(landmark, frame):
    return (int(landmark.x * frame.shape[1]), int(landmark.y * frame.shape[0]))

mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    _, frame = cap.read()
    try:
        frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        pose_results = pose.process(frame_rgb)
        # mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, pose_results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)

        nose = pose_results.pose_landmarks.landmark[0]
        left_eye = pose_results.pose_landmarks.landmark[1]
        right_eye = pose_results.pose_landmarks.landmark[5]
        mouth_left = pose_results.pose_landmarks.landmark[9]
        mouth_right = pose_results.pose_landmarks.landmark[10]
        euclidean_distance_times_2 = 2 * ((nose.x - left_eye.x) ** 2 + (nose.y - left_eye.y) ** 2) ** 0.5
        cv2.circle(frame, (int(nose.x * frame.shape[1]), int(nose.y * frame.shape[0])), int(euclidean_distance_times_2 * frame.shape[1]), (0, 255, 255), -1)

        red= (0, 0, 255)
        heart_size = 1

        left_eye_coords = landmark_to_image_coords(left_eye, frame)
        right_eye_coords = landmark_to_image_coords(right_eye, frame)

        draw_heart(frame, left_eye_coords, heart_size, red)
        draw_heart(frame, right_eye_coords, heart_size, red)

        mouth_left_c = landmark_to_image_coords(mouth_left, frame)
        mouth_right_c = landmark_to_image_coords(mouth_right, frame)

        cv2.line(frame, mouth_left_c, mouth_right_c, red, 2)
        cv2.line(frame, mouth_left_c, (int(mouth_left_c[0] - 20), int(mouth_left_c[1] + 20)), (0, 255, 0), 2)
        cv2.line(frame, mouth_right_c, (int(mouth_right_c[0] + 20), int(mouth_right_c[1] + 20)), (0, 255, 0), 2)

        cv2.imshow('Output', frame)
    except:
        break

    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Is it possible to replace the drawings with actual PNG images instead of drawings? How would this be done? Thanks!

Comment: For example, instead of drawing a yellow circle, you resize and use a yellow PNG image, and instead of drawing a heart we resize and use a PNG heart image, ETC.

Comment: Yes, the idea I can think of is to find a drawing of a heart ( assuming you think of heart) with a uniform background, e.g. white. Make a copy of the image, transform the copy to grayscale (to have just one channel instead of 3), which would be easier to work with, and assign pixel values with coordinates where pixel value != 255 (dismissing background) the appropriate places in the target image (frame). Of course, reducing the heart image size accordingly.

Comment: Since the person can move closer or further away from the camera, I propose to make the factor by which we shrink the object dependent on, for example, the distance of the landmark of the nose from the landmark of the mouth. Then the hearts will be larger when the person is closer to the camera and smaller when they move away.

Comment: Hey @forest-spells, could you help me out with the new question below? It's similar to the one above, but can't figure it out. Thanks!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78209901/python-mediapipe-replace-chest-pose-landmark-lines-with-custom-image?noredirect=1#comment137882826_78209901

Comment: @Vakindu I can take a look, do you still need help?

Comment: Yes please! Thanks! Kindly follow the link. Thanks again.