# Python Mediapipe replace chest pose landmark lines with custom image

Tags: python, opencv, graphics, drawing, mediapipe

I'm using a webcam to stream a video and would like to use mediapipe to estimate and replace a user's chest pose landmark line drawings with the custom shield image below.

The code I currently have below is only drawing landmark lines.

Could someone please help me alter the code below to achieve the result as described?

Thanks in advance!

Current image result:

[image: Current result image]

Shield Image to Use:

[image: shield to add]

Desired Image result:

[image: Desired image result]

The current code:

```py
import cv2
import mediapipe as mp

## initialize pose estimator
mp_drawing = mp.solutions.drawing_utils
mp_pose = mp.solutions.pose
pose = mp_pose.Pose(min_detection_confidence=0.5, min_tracking_confidence=0.5)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while cap.isOpened():
    # read frame
    _, frame = cap.read()
    try:
         # resize the frame for portrait video
         # frame = cv2.resize(frame, (350, 600))
         # convert to RGB
         frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
         
         # process the frame for pose detection
         pose_results = pose.process(frame_rgb)
         # print(pose_results.pose_landmarks)
         
         # draw skeleton on the frame
         mp_drawing.draw_landmarks(frame, pose_results.pose_landmarks, mp_pose.POSE_CONNECTIONS)
         # display the frame
         cv2.imshow('Output', frame)
    except:
         break
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
         break
          
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Mediapipe replace pose landmark line drawings with custom image drawings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78201163/python-mediapipe-replace-pose-landmark-line-drawings-with-custom-image-drawings)

Comment: No. Needs to be replaced with an image, not a drawing.

Comment: but the title is the same and you accepted the other answer. did it not actually answer your question? in any case, it's a *drawing* problem, not a *vision* problem, and the code you present doesn't try to draw either lines or pictures.

Comment: @forest-spells Hey, could you help me out here?